# How to use mongodb of another droplet in Digitalocean

Tags: mongodb, meteor, deployment, digital-ocean

Let's say I have two server droplets in digitalocean, but I only want to use the mongodb of the 1st server. How can I connect the 2nd server to the 1st server's mongodb?

What would be the mongourl that i should set on the 2nd server upon deployment?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`MONGO_URL=mongodb://12.34.56.78:27017/db_name`

Where `12.34.56.78:27017` is the MongoDB droplet's IP and port, and `db_name` is a custom database name ("meteor" by default).

Comment: you should also point that you should use the 'private ip' feature of DigitalOcean and make sure your MongoDB is only exposed to the private IP (i.e. run it with config set to bind only to the private IP), otherwise the DB will be exposed to the world!

Comment: @aedm & MrE Thanks for the responses! We proceeded to try compose.io for our external database.